# NodeJS & Gulp Streams & Vinyl File Objects- Gulp Wrapper for NPM package producing incorrect output

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp, file-encodings

#### Goal

I am currently trying to write a Gulp wrapper for [NPM Flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) that can be easily used in Gulp tasks. I feel this would be useful to the Node community and also accomplish my goal. **[The repository is here for everyone to view , contribute to, play with and pull request.](https://github.com/DanielCaspers/gulp-flat)** I am attempting to  make flattened (using dot notation) copies of multiple JSON files. I then want to copy them to the same folder and just modify the file extension to go from *.json to *.flat.json.

#### My problem

The results I am getting back in my JSON files look like vinyl-files or byte code. For example, I expect output like
  `"views.login.usernamepassword.login.text": "Login"`, but I am getting something like `{"0":123,"1":13,"2":10,"3":9,"4":34,"5":100,"6":105`  ...etc

#### My approach

*I am brand new to developing Gulp tasks and node modules, so definitely keep your eyes out for fundamentally wrong things.*

The repository will be the most up to date code, but I'll also try to keep the question up to date with it too.

**Gulp-Task File**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({camelize: true});
var gulpFlat = require('gulp-flat');
var gulpRename = require('gulp-rename');
var flatten = require('flat');

gulp.task('language:file:flatten', function () {

return gulp.src(gulp.files.lang_file_src)
    .pipe(gulpFlat())
    .pipe(gulpRename( function (path){
        path.extname = '.flat.json'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("App/Languages"));
});
```

**Node module's index.js (A.k.a what I hope becomes gulp-flat)**

```
var through = require('through2');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var flatten = require('flat');
var PluginError = gutil.PluginError;

// consts
const PLUGIN_NAME = 'gulp-flat';


// plugin level function (dealing with files)
function flattenGulp() {

    // creating a stream through which each file will pass
    var stream = through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
        if (file.isBuffer()) {

             //FIXME: I believe this is the problem line!!
            var flatJSON = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(
                flatten(file.contents)));
            file.contents = flatJSON;
    }

    if (file.isStream()) {

        this.emit('error', new PluginError(PLUGIN_NAME, 'Streams not supported! NYI'));
        return cb();
    }

    // make sure the file goes through the next gulp plugin
    this.push(file);
    // tell the stream engine that we are done with this file
    cb();
});

// returning the file stream
return stream;
}

// exporting the plugin main function
module.exports = flattenGulp;
```

#### Resources

- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/README.md
- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/using-buffers.md
- https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

Comment: Good on you for making an npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about where the error is. The fix is simple. You just need to parse `file.contents`, since the `flatten` function operates on an *object*, not on a Buffer.

```
...
var flatJSON = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(
  flatten(JSON.parse(file.contents))));
file.contents = flatJSON;
...
```

That should fix your problem.

And since you are new to the Gulp plugin thing, I hope you don't mind if I make a suggestion. You might want to consider giving your users the option to prettify the JSON output. To do so, just have your main function accept an `options` object, and then you can do something like this:

```
...
var flatJson = flatten(JSON.parse(file.contents));
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(flatJson, null, options.pretty ? 2 : null);
file.contents = new Buffer(jsonString);
...
```

You might find that the options object comes in useful for other things, if you plan to expand on your plugin in future.

Feel free to have a look at the repository for a plugin I wrote called [gulp-transform](https://github.com/akim-mcmath/gulp-transform). I am happy to answer any questions about it. (For example, I could give you some guidance on implementing the streaming-mode version of your plugin if you would like).

#### Update

I decided to take you up on your invitation for contributions. You can view my fork [here](https://github.com/akim-mcmath/gulp-flat) and the issue I opened up [here](https://github.com/DanielCaspers/gulp-flat/issues/1). You're welcome to use as much or as little as you like, and in case you really like it, I can always submit a pull request. Hopefully it gives you some ideas at least.

Thank you for getting this project going.

Comment: I will look more closely at the rest of the answer in the morning. One note is that I realize that gulp requests a paradigm of doing one thing well. This is why I show the "gulp task file" above, which gives some scope into the problem. I never intended to "bake in" gulp-rename for example; that was just the problem in full. Thanks!

Comment: @BlazeBiker OK, I see the gulp task file now. Somehow I was under the impression you wanted to make the renaming part of the project, but I see now that I was mistaken.